# How to clear/reset mocks in Vitest

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vitest

I have a simple composable `useRoles` which I need to test

```js
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "./store";

export default function useRoles() {
  const store = useStore();

  const isLearner = computed(() => store.state.profile.currentRole === "learner");

  return {
    isLearner
  };
}
```

My approach of testing it is the following

```js
import { afterEach, expect } from "vitest";
import useRoles from "./useRoles";

describe("useRoles", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks();
    vi.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("should verify values when is:Learner", () => { // works
    vi.mock("./store", () => ({
      useStore: () => ({
        state: {
          profile: {
            currentRole: "learner"
          },
        },
      }),
    }));

    const { isLearner } = useRoles();

    expect(isLearner.value).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should verify values when is:!Learner", () => { //fails
    vi.mock("./store", () => ({
      useStore: () => ({
        state: {
          profile: {
            currentRole: "admin"
          },
        },
      }),
    }));

    const { isLearner } = useRoles(); // Values are from prev mock

    expect(isLearner.value).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

And `useStore` is just a simple function that I intended to mock

```js
export function useStore() {
  return {/**/};
}
```

The first test runs successfully, it has all the mock values I implemented but the problem is that it's not resetting for each test (not resetting at all). The second test has the old values from the previous mock.

I have used

```js
vi.clearAllMocks();
vi.resetAllMocks();
```

but for some reason clear or reset is not happening.

How can I clear `vi.mock` value for each test?

## Solution

As it turned out I should not be called `vi.mock` multiple times. That was the main mistake

> Substitutes all imported modules from provided path with another module. You can use configured Vite aliases inside a path. The call to vi.mock is hoisted, so it doesn't matter where you call it. It will always be executed before all imports.

> Vitest statically analyzes your files to hoist vi.mock. It means that you cannot use vi that was not imported directly from vitest package (for example, from some utility file)

[Docs](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock)

My fixed solution is below.

```
import useRoles from "./useRoles";
import { useStore } from "./store"; // Required the mock to work

vi.mock("./store");

describe("useRoles", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks();
    vi.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("should verify values when is:Learner", () => {
    // @ts-ignore it is a mocked instance so we can use any vitest methods
    useStore.mockReturnValue({
      state: {
        profile: {
          currentRole: "learner",
        },
      },
    });

    const { isLearner } = useRoles();

    expect(isLearner.value).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should verify values when is:!Learner", () => {
    // You need to use either @ts-ignore or typecast it
    // as following (<MockedFunction<typeof useStore>>useStore)
    // since original function has different type but vitest mock transformed it
    (<MockedFunction<typeof useStore>>useStore).mockReturnValue({
      state: {
        profile: {
          currentRole: "admin",
        },
      },
    });

    const { isLearner } = useRoles();

    expect(isLearner.value).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

`vitest = v0.23.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and was able to find a workaround. In your case it should look like this:

```js
import { afterEach, expect } from "vitest";
import useRoles from "./useRoles";

vi.mock("./store");

describe("useRoles", () => {
  it("should verify values when is:Learner", async () => {
    const store = await import("./store");
    store.useStore = await vi.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({
      useStore: () => ({
        state: {
          profile: {
            currentRole: "learner"
          },
        },
      }),
    });

    const { isLearner } = useRoles();

    expect(isLearner.value).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should verify values when is:!Learner", async () => {
    const store = await import("./store");
    store.useStore = await vi.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({
      useStore: () => ({
        state: {
          profile: {
            currentRole: "admin"
          },
        },
      }),
    });

    const { isLearner } = useRoles(); // Value is from current mock

    expect(isLearner.value).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Havn't tested it but as a workaround, I believe the dynamic imports should do the trick. Thanks

Comment: Did not work for mocked API calls, but thanks for this

Comment: Yeah, stumbled upon that problem as well @jchua, see [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544569/mocking-dependency-while-testing-a-page-with-nuxt-test-utils). Feel free to answer it, if you found a solution.