# Mocking dependency while testing a page with @nuxt/test-utils

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to test if my nuxt page renders the content, it receives from a composable. In the real scenario, the composable would fetch information from an external API. To keep my tests independet, I'd like to mock the returned value during tests.

That's a simple reproduction setup:

`./pages/index.vue`:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import useStoreName from '~~/composables/useStoreName';
const storeName = useStoreName();
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ storeName }}</h1>
</template>
```

`./composables/useStoreName.ts`:

```js
export default function () {
    return 'original value';
}
```

I tried the following to test my page, which does not work:

`./tests/pages/index.test.ts`:

```js
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { $fetch, setup } from '@nuxt/test-utils';

vi.mock('~~/composables/useStoreName', () => ({
    storeName: 'mocked value'
}));

describe('ssr', async () => {
    await setup({ server: true, browser: false });

    it('renders mocked store name', async () => {
        const html = await $fetch('/');
        expect(html).toContain('mocked value');
    });
});
```

Resulting error code:

```
AssertionError: expected '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html data-head-attr…' to include 'mocked value'
```

Comment: As in the example https://test-utils.nuxtjs.org/api-reference/app-testing#example You're supposed to first render the page, then fetch the data and set it to the body, afterwards search for this text in body of page not in the response of $fetch.

Comment: The example doesn't show how to "set the data to the body". What do you mean by that? My problem is, that the hydration data for my page is coming from an external API, but I want to mock that API in my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the server the @nuxt/test-utils starts is running on its own context. The mock you built up is only "visible" on the test, not the test server.

You can modify the server in the setup with plugins like this:

```
await setup({
  server: true,
  browser: false,
  nuxtConfig: {
    runtimeConfig: { valueForPlugin: 'mocked value' },
    plugins: ['~/test/plugins/mockstore']
  }
});
```

Then, you implement the mock inside that plugin so that it overrides the value when the test server is running. You can provide values from the test to the test server through the runtimeConfig.

The plugin would then looks something like this (haven't tested this pseudo code to work):

```
import { vi } from 'vitest';
export default defineNuxtPlugin((_nuxtApp) => {
  vi.mock('~~/composables/useStoreName', () => ({
    storeName: _nuxtApp.$config.valueForPlugin
  }));
})
```

Comment: Didn't have a chance to verify that this works yet, but it looks alright. Thanks for providing that answer!